# Диспетчер задач зависает после запуска

Tags: windows, windows-11

После запуска диспетчера задач - он работает пару секунд (трекает процессы и нагрузку) и останавливает треккинг, при это само приложение диспетчера задач работает и все кнопки кликабельны.

При этом, если закрыть диспетчер, а не убить процесс в нём же, то он зависает с ошибкой "Приложение не отвечает"

У меня стоит 32гб ddr4 и i5-12400f, так что дело не в железе

Comment: как вариант, какая нибудь дрянь вроде незванного майнера вполне может его блочить. можно попробовать нестандартный диспетчер. рекомендую глянуть на `Process Explorer`(ищите на офф сайте ms) p.s. древовидная сортировка в нём - имба :3